# Структура asp.net mvc приложения

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Здравствуйте. Недавно меня заинтересовало, как красиво преобразовывать данные для передачи в вид и вообще, как грамотно делать приложения на [asp.net](http://asp.net) mvc. [Здесь мне ответили.](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/18/143507/675851/#post675851)

Я честно говоря не слишком понимаю эти термины пока не увижу код воочию.
Если кто-то программирует использую такой подход, то выложите здесь примеры или киньте в скайпе: [umnick.jo](http://umnick.jo). Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В проекте должны быть 2 независимых модели данных: доменная модель и "вью модель". Чтобы преобразовать сущности доменной модели в сущности вью модели (или наоборот) для дальнейшего отображения во вьюхах удобно использовать [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) или любой другой аналог.

*Пример:*

Этап конфигурации:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WatchList, WatchListData>()
      .ForMember(m => m.IsContainUsers, a => a.MapFrom(p => p.Subjects.Count > 0));
```

Обычно обе модели во многом совпадают (одинаковые свойства) и в подобном случае конфигурация будет состоять из одной строки создания "мапа", либо как в примере у вью-модели есть дополнительное свойство IsContainUsers, которое и сконфигурировано.

Этап преобразования:

```
var domainWatchList = GetFromDatabase();
var viewWatchList = Mapper.Map<WatchList, WatchListData>(domainWatchList);
```

Comment: Вот вот интересно. Можно пример из приложения? Я уверен у вас это есть. Напишите мне в скайп. Мне это очень нужно.

Comment: Ещё одна просьба. Мне интересно, с чем сопоставляется имя класса из бизнес слоя? С именем сущности именем контроллера или как? Было бы идеально увидеть структуру готового проекта. Ну типа список файлов.

Comment: Что касается структуры проекта - посмотрите на эту для примера: http://sharparchitecture.net/. Имя класса доменной модели обычно сопоставляется с таблицей в БД.

Comment: Кстате на основе выше указанной архитектуры вполне можно строить свои приложения - даже шаблон для студии есть, но если у вас мини проект то смысла особо в этом нет.

Comment: Ну доменной это понятно. Но что касается бизнес, то тут посмотрю. Спасибо!